What strategies are effective at curtailing overly aggressive deleting of compliant questions and answers?
In our community, it only takes three delete votes to delete a post.
I'm looking for some advice (hopefully coming from experience) on what actions we might take to improve our review process so that fewer posts are deleted when they fully comply with our community's rules.
By the way, I did review Aggressive closing of questions suggestion, but did not feel that it answers my question.

What you've described here appears to be a problem that you have with the actions of one user or a very small number of users. If you feel those users are behaving inappropriately for the site, and you have been unsuccessful in discussing the actions with them in comments or chat, or you are unwilling to do so, then you should raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on one of the affected posts, or one of the posts by that user, and explain in the flag what the problem is that you see.

If it's a site-wide issue, and not with specific users, then you can bring up the site-wide issue on the meta site for the site where the problem exists. You can then discuss it there to see if some resolution can be found that works for the site.

@Makyen I'm looking for people's experience dealing with this issue on other sites. After learning more, I was planning to then write a post for SE Space Meta.

@Makyen To your second comment, the usual flag-raising process is not always effective and it's asymmetric. It's like fighting a losing battle. Unfortunately, it is much easier to delete a post than it is to get the community and/or moderators to reverse the deletion.

@Makyen To your third comment, this question is not about a specific user. This question is asking about strategies that have been tried in the past across all SE sites, and whether any were particularly effective.

This is a thorny problem, and not really easily fixed. I don't think a network-wide answer is best here. You would be better served coming to your site's meta, and coming correctly. Come with a big list of answers that were deleted wrongfully (general guidance is wrong answers are downvoted, not necessarily deleted, but your site can choose to change this), and make your case for why this course of action is wrong and what to do instead. Cite sources that fit the discussion, and be prepared for opposition. You're trying to direct policy here, so be prepared for an answer you disagree with

@Spevacus I do like what you're advising here. Logistically, is it possible for a non-mod to filter for deleted answers to make it easier to find posts to review? There are a lot of posts on the site. We're kind of back to the asymmetry issue again if it's fundamentally hard to build a good case that change is needed.

Non-mods can browse recently (up to 30 days) deleted posts on moderator tools. Other than that, only mods can search for all posts.

@MetaAndrewT. That was very helpful! By reviewing I discovered that another user seems to be hunting down old answers that had accumulated two "delete" votes. They are casting the third and final vote on these posts. I suspect that this qualifies as frowned-upon behavior.

I’m reasonably certain that I am one of the “ two or three other members of the community who are generally inclined to cast a second or third delete vote after a first vote has been cast” but I’m not robo-reviewing. The reason that I’ve lots of second/third DVis because I review posts that got some delete votes to see if they need more (should be deleted) and just slipped through the cracks (which happens more than you’d think). I don’t robo-review (and I’d say the majority of said posts I don’t wind up VTDing). flag for mod intervention, they’ll review it, fix it if there is any problem…

I suggest that you write a post on Stack Exchange Meta to document your process and the criteria that you are personally using to decide when a post should be deleted and contrast those criteria to officially documented criteria. Then see if you can make the case that we should all adopt your criteria. In the meantime, there's no rule that says "Should be deleted if Starship doesn't like it." and no rule that says "Should be deleted if it already accumulated two delete votes."

@phil1008 Obviously. My point was that I don’t believe that I am doing anything wrong. The reason VTD exists is such that 3 trusted users must agree that the post should be deleted. I don’t like it or it has delete votes is not the reason I do or do not VTD stuff.

In the review queue, when I see a post that I think should probably be deleted, I'm forced to pick a reason. This drives home the point that I should not delete the post unless I can point to one of the legitimate reasons (these are listed in my other post). Posts should not be deleted because three out of I-don't-know-how-many-but-it's-a-lot of trusted voters agree. A trusted voter is trusted to follow the rules of the site. It does not mean that the user suddenly becomes qualified to invent and apply their own independent set of criteria for deleting a post.

@phil1008 Obviously. The fact that I did not have to select a reason when going through this does not mean that I was not voting to deleted these posts for a legitimate reason.

@phil1008 - often, users have to choose the closest reason, as the system only has a limited number of boilerplate reasons. Posts absolutely SHOULD be deleted if the required number of trusted users agree. That is explicitly why we have that functionality. Whether or not a post already has 2 delete votes is irrelevant if a user sees it is low quality - in their opinion - and deserves their delete vote.

Upvote
A question or answer can't be deleted by the community unless it has a negative score. Upvote it. That single action can make a -1-score post with two delete votes into a 0-score post that is impossible for the community to delete.
If it's a -2-score post, that really doesn't actually deserve to be (somehow?), upvote and try to convince someone else to do so too using the site's chat. Or meta chat? Or meta. I'm actually not 100% clear on what will be preferred on most sites in the network; here at Space SE I'd try the chat first and Meta second and leave the meta chat alone altogether.
If the post needs improvement, improve it and upvote. The improvement edit will bump it on that SE's page and garner attention. If it's an actual improvement, and other people agree with that, hopefully they'll upvote too.
